# LOG4J2: Disable "No log4j2 configuration file found.." print when configuring programmatically

Tags: java, log4j2

I am not using any XML configuration file, rather I am setting the logger configuration *programmatically*. The logger works correctly but just when I call the first line of the code below, a warning `ERROR` message shows up to tell me that the configuration file was not found and default configuration will be used.

But I don't want this message to be displayed on the console every time I rung the program because I will *programmatically* add the configuration myself.

The message:

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
```

It comes when I call the code below:

```
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
```

Or if I get the root logger first:

```
Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
```

Is there some kind of property that I can set to disable this message from being displayed? Or another approach?.

<sup>**NOTE**: I disabled another notification regarding Log4j2 JMX by setting the property **`-Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true`**. But I couldn't find for this one.</sup>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add the following system property in order to not show that message:

```
-Dorg.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level=OFF
```

Alternatively, and more simply:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.status.StatusLogger;

...

StatusLogger.getLogger().setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can simply do this in your main class.

```
static {
    StatusLogger.getLogger().setLevel(Level.OFF);
}
```

Comment: ~This~ is the answer. :)

Comment: Saved my day too. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement initialize method for proper initialization of log4j configurations from code.

Check the "How do I configure log4j2 in code without a configuration file" section in below page which provides the source code also.

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html

Comment: Yes but all the initialize methods inside that class require you to give location of configuration file.